# Invalid flag but question is closed?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged a question as an exact duplicate, but it was marked invalid and then the question was closed? Was my flag valid or not?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing probably because they thought that you should've voted to close instead of flagging... but you don't have that priv yet.

Comment: Isn't that something you can click on? Meaning you can flag your flag as invalid?

Comment: @Ivo : No, the **Invalid** is not a link.

Comment: ... the flag in question is over a month old.

Comment: @Sathya : Yea, I just picked it up, was looking through the new flag interface and saw that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flag might have been marked invalid by another mod but closed later by me. (There's a ~24 hour gap between the time the flag was marked invalid and the time the post was closed).

I'd assume the post might have been voted to close after your flag was marked invalid and was picked up by me to close.